# Cloud Function Error runQuery() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

i want to run a schedule query  when HTTP cloud function is triggered
This written python 3.7

```
import time from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 
import Timestamp from google.cloud 
import bigquery_datatransfer_v1

def runQuery (parent, requested_run_time):
client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()
projectid = '917960740952' # Enter your projectID here
transferid = '630d5269-0000-2622-98d2-3c286d4314be' 
parent = client.project_transfer_config_path(projectid, transferid)
start_time = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time() + 10))
response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(parent, requested_run_time=start_time)
print(response)
```

Any help Please

Comment: Please include the code as *text* in the question, rather than as a screenshot. Additionally, it *sounds* like the error is actually in the calling code. Please provide more details.

Comment: No. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and ask yourself if *you* were trying to answer this question, does it contain all the information you'd want to see, as clearly presented as possible?

Comment: Readable now :)

Comment: Is it an HTTP cloud function? Or event-triggered?

Comment: HTTP cloud Function ..

Comment: If runQuery is an entry point, then I think it must accepts one parameter - request. All other parameters you have to read from the request.

Comment: @MaxZolotenko  Thanks Max  can you help me how that is written as am new to this

Comment: This is now more readable, but I suspect it's invalid Python due to the lack of indentation in the function...

Comment: Try this **def runQuery (parent, requested_run_time):** replace with this **def runQuery (request):**

Comment: @MaxZolotenko  i got below error   although my location is not us 
The requested transfer config (projects/917960740952/locations/us/transferConfigs/630d5269-0000-2622-98d2-3c286d4314be) was not found.

Comment: I changed the parent path to be and worked with me 
parent = 'projects/917960740952/locations/europe/transferConfigs/630d5269-0000-2622-98d2-3c286d4314be'

Answer (score 0):

I changed the parent path to be and worked with me

```
parent = 'projects/917960740952/locations/europe/transferConfigs/630d5269-0000-2622-98d2-3c286d4314be'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1
import time
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp


def runQuery(request):
    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()
    PROJECT_ID = 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME'
    LOCATION_NAME = 'YOUR_TRANSFER_REGION'
    TRANSFER_CONFIG_ID = 'YOUR_TRANSFER_ID'
    parent = "projects/{0}/locations/{1}/transferConfigs/{2}".format(PROJECT_ID, LOCATION_NAME, TRANSFER_CONFIG_ID)
    start_time = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time() + 10))
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(parent, requested_run_time=start_time)
    print(response)
```